# reasons to define a class of a mixin in LESS

Tags: less

For example in Bootstrap's source I found, mixins.less defines:

```
.clearfix() {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

and utilities.less:

```
.clearfix {
  .clearfix();
}
```

I understand it is useful to have a clearfix class, but will there be any reason other than have only mixins and no classes in mixins.less, to not define a class instead of a mixin in mixins.less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Flexibility

Since Bootstrap is a library, they realize that some people will not want to use classes from Bootstrap, but will want to use the mixins. By keeping the separation, a user can import `mixins.less` and apply `.clearfix()` into their own code under their own class name(s), *without it actually creating an output of a `.clearfix` class itself*. At the same time, if one wants to use the whole Bootstrap library, they want to provide an actual class by the name `.clearfix` for users of the whole library.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reasons except keeping the library organization consistent (E.g. "mixins.less should not produce any CSS and utilities.less should have only classes").